# Create SQLite table from an inherited class

Tags: xamarin.forms, sqlite-net

I want to create a SQLite table based on the `GroupEntity` class which inherits from the `Entity` class.

When I try to create a table directly from GroupEntity class without inheritance - table creates successfully.

I am using SQLite-net, Version=1.4.118.0 in Xamarin.Forms PCL project.

```cs
public class Entity
{        
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public int CreatedById { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
        public int ModifiedById { get; set; }
}
public class GroupEntity : Entity
{
        [SQLite.PrimaryKey]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int PhotoFileId { get; set; }
        public int UnreadMessageCount { get; set; }
        public Guid LastMessageId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you please update what is the status of your question now(after 2 years) is it still happening with the latest XF version? PCL is deprecated now.